# How to represent a transformation in REST?

Tags: rest

I want to write a service which takes an xml file (any xml file) and a couple of parameters as input and produces a transformed xml file as its output. So, for example, if I need a service that removes profanity, the parameters would be a severity treshold (on a scale from `darn` to `f***`) and the mode of transformation (`f***ing`, `f@%%ing` or `flipping`) The actual format of the xml is irrelevant, the output will always be the same format as the input. (Before you point out that this is a futile exercise: this isn't the service I actually want to build obviously.)

Although I've used REST-based services, I'm kind of new to designing them and I don't really know how to fit this in the resource/collection idiom and more importantly, how to make it really REST-like, avoiding WADLs and making the interface self-describing instead. Or is REST simply not the right tool for this?

Comment: Sounds f***ing difficult to me

Comment: @skaffman I don't necessarily want to shoehorn it into REST, I just want to know if it's just my lack of experience that makes it hard to fit or is it really not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Httpbis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-13#page-17) :

> POST is designed to allow a uniform
> method to cover    the following
> functions: ... Providing a block of
> data, such as the result of submitting
> a
> form, to a data-handling process;

For example:

```
POST /ProfanityRemover?level=3
ContentType: application/xml

<Foo>
  <Blah>Damn</Blah>
</Foo>

=>
200 OK
ContentType: application/xml

<Foo>
  <Blah>Poop</Blah>
</Foo>
```

Comment: This looks promising but how do I document what parameters are available, and what are the accepted values of them? Some sort of discovery using hyperlinks? Is there a standard or at least a fairly common practice for that?

Comment: @biziclop  At the root url of your service return a document that contains URI templates that provide access to your ProfanityRemover resource.  See http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-gregorio-uritemplate-04

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was after, thank you very much. And I reckon I could have another url which returns the possible values that could be substituted on a GET.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question to answer from a REST perspective because the service you describe doesn't have any server-side resources - there's no server state to transfer in the requests and responses. All of the state is client-side. Traditionally, this would be handled by a GET, but you probably don't want to write an XML document into a query string.

Probably you be be best using the method suggested by Darrel Miller. POST to your desired endpoint with the document as the body, and have the response's body be the updated document.